# May I omit "do" in a dependent clause?

Tags: do-support

In a sentence like this:

> Many people realize that they didn't do any wrongdoings, so they cannot understand why they have to be punished.
>   *or*
>
> Many ..., so they cannot understand why **do** they have to be punished.*

Which sentence is right?

I know in an independent question like "Why do you fight?" we cannot omit the "do". But in a clause like the example I gave above, may I omit the "do"?

Answer (score 5):

**SHORT ANSWER:**
You must omit it.

**LONG ANSWER:**
*Wh-* words like *who* or *when* or *how* or *why* require inversion and *DO-support* only when the clauses they head are formal questions. When these words head a relative clause or a dependent clause, the remainder of the clause follows normal order.

> **He has to be punished [*implied:* because X].**
> **I do not understand. Why does he have to be punished?** ... *Why* ‘replaces’ the implicit *because X* and moves to the head. *Why does he have to be punished?* is an ordinary question and requires both *Do-support* and inversion to get an auxiliary verb into second place.
> **I do not understand why he has to be punished.**  ... Again, *Why* replaces *because X* and moves to the head. *Why he has to be punished* is a dependent clause, the object of *understand*, so the remainder of the clause follows in ordinary order.
> **The man who has to be punished is innocent!** ... *Who* replaces *he*; as the subject of the relative clause it is already in first position; the remainder of the clause follows in ordinary order.
>
> **I have to punish him.**
> **I do not understand. Who<sup>†</sup> do you have to punish?** ... *Who* replaces *him* and moves to the head. *Who do you have to punish?* is an ordinary question and requires inversion and *Do-support* to get an auxiliary verb into second place.
> **I do not understand who<sup>†</sup> you have to punish.** ... *Who* replaces *him* and moves to the head. *Who you have to punish* is a dependent clause, so after the movement the remainder follows in ordinary order.
> **The man who<sup>†</sup> you have to punish is innocent!** ... *Who* replaces *him* and moves to the head. *Who you have to punish* is a relative clause, so after the movement the remainder follows in ordinary order.

Note that *have* in the construction *have to* is a lexical verb, not an auxiliary; accordingly it requires *DO-support* in questions. If you replace *have* to with the modal auxiliary *must*, *DO-support* is not required.

> **I must punish him.**
> **I do not understand. Who<sup>†</sup> must you punish?**
> **I do not understand who<sup>†</sup> you must punish.**
> **The man who<sup>†</sup> you must punish is innocent!**

---

<sup>†</sup> Strict formal usage requires *whom*.

Comment: I am very glad that you gave a very detailed answer to me, which is very helpful. Thanks a lot, Stoney.

Comment: Huddleston and Pullum say that for some speakers, "Have I to sign for both forms?" (meaning "Do I have to sign both forms?") is acceptable.  They lump this *have* in with the *have* of possession, calling it "static *have*", saying it's lexical for most speakers but auxiliary for some (particularly older BrE speakers).  The *have* that is always auxiliary they label "perfect *have*", while the *have* that is always lexical (as in *to have a fit*) they label "dynamic *have*".

Comment: @snailboat I think Profs H & P are correct in making the distinction; but I think it's a fossil from older usage, under which *HAVE* was **always** permitted to act syntactically like an auxiliary, without *DO* support (*Have you any treacle?*), regardless of its function. *BE* of course is always **required** to act like an auxiliary.