# How do you think about me? or How you think about me?

Tags: meaning, difference

Which is more correct?

> How do you think about me? ***or*** How you think about me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As referenced in [this answer to another question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6536/may-i-omit-do-in-a-dependent-clause/6539#6539), "*Wh-* words like *who* or *when* or *how* or *why* require inversion and *DO-support* only when the clauses they head are formal questions."

In this case, you are using a *wh-* word ("how") in a question, so DO-support is required, and therefore your first version is correct.

However!

It seems very likely that you have the wrong *wh-* word.  It looks as if you want to ask someone what their opinion of you is; that is, you want an answer like "I think you're very smart" or "You're a really nice guy".  In this case, you really need to ask "*What* do you think about me?", or more normally, "What do you think *of* me?"

Comment: +1 But I realized on reading this that the sentence you quoted could be misunderstood; so I rewrote it *in situ* and have taken the liberty of making the same correction to your quotation.

Comment: Yes, but Google Books confirms my first thought. [*"What do you think **about** him"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22What+do+you+think+about+him%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl):22K, [*"What do you think **of** him"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22What+do+you+think+of+him%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl):300K. It's a pretty decisive preference overall.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I thought about making that additional correction, but "about" felt reasonable enough that tweaking it didn't seem warranted.  I'll add a note about it.

Comment: Thank you very much 
What about: How do men think about women?
Yes, my question about Do-support